# Scala call lambda from map

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
val actions = Map(
"index" ->  Map(
  "description" -> "Makes CAEServer index project with provided project_id "
  , "usage" -> "index project_id"
  , "action" -> (
    (args: Array[String]) => {
      if (checkSecondArgument(args, "Project ID wasn't specified. Please supply project ID.")) {
        new CAEServer(args{0}).index(args{2})
      }
    }
)))

actions{providedAction}{"action"}(args)
```

and when I'm trying to compile it, compiler says

```
error: MainConsole.this.actions.apply(providedAction).apply("action") of type java.lang.Object does not take parameters
[INFO]       actions{providedAction}{"action"}(args)
[INFO]       ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

What's wrong?

Comment: That is probably because actions has type `Map[String, Map[String, Any]]` where `Any` doesn't take parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember: Scala is statically typed.

When you create the (outer) `Map`, Scala infers the type of `actions` based on what you put in there. The most restrictive but still matching type (so called least-upper-bound) is:

```
Map[String,Map[String,Object]]
```

So a `Map` that maps `Strings` to `Maps` that map `Strings` to `Objects`. So when you retrieve any element, it will be of type `Object`, not `Function` so you cannot call it.

You should use case classes:

```
case class ActionElement(
    description: String,
    usage: String,
    action: Array[String] => CAEServer)

val actions = Map("index" ->  ActionElement(
   "Makes CAEServer index project with provided project_id ",
   "index project_id",
   args => { if (checkSecondArgument(args, "Project ID wasn't ...")) {
     new CAEServer(args{0}).index(args{2})
   }
))
```

Now you can call:

```
actions(providedAction).action(args)
```